# Are elevated platelet levels (yet, still anemic) a symptom of endometriosis? Connection?

Tags: symptoms, endometriosis, white-blood-count, platelet-count, anemia

for about two years now, my platelet levels have been consistently elevated; not off the charts or anything to be overly alarming, but consistently coming in at about 500.

And oddly enough, I'm still anemic, so I have to take iron supplements. I thought people with anemia had low platelet levels, yet mine are high so it doesn't make sense to me.

I have seen a hematologist, and she can't seem to identify anything abnormal to indicate why I have elevated platelets. Also, my WBC is high too, but only about 15.

My GP & OBGYN think that I **might have endometriosis. Would this explain why I have elevated platelets, WBC, but yet am still anemic? Is there any correlation between platelet levels and endometriosis or no?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the laboratories, the upper limit for thrombocytes count varies between 350,000 to 450,000/microL (350 to 450 x 109 /L).

Thrombocytosis refers to the condition where the thrombocyte count is above this upper limit. There are different categories for thrombocytosis: reactive thrombocytosis, autonomous thrombocytosis (in the presence of a myeloproliferative or myelodysplasic disorder) and essential thrombocytosis (a type of myeloproliferative disease).

Here a non exhaustive list of the causes of thrombocytosis:

- Nonmalignant hematologic conditions (acute blood loss, iron deficiency anemia, acute hemolytic anemia)
- Malignant conditions
- Acute and chronic inflammatory conditions (Rheumatologic disorders, vasculitides, inflammatory bowel diseases)
- Infections (chronic infections, acute viral or bacterial infections)
- Reaction to medications (glucocorticoids)
- Tissue damage (myocardial infarction, acute pancreatitis, burns)

I haven't found a direct link between endometriosis and thrombocytosis. However, acute bleeding (which can occur in endometriosis) and resulting iron deficiency anemia (which you suggest you have) are both causes for thrombocytosis.

*Sources: Tefferi A. Approach to the patient with thrombocytosis. Uptodate. August 2016*